# $ not being recognized in Javascript/jQuery code - trying to animate a module with class name="jeff"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am receiving the following error message:

> $ is not defined.

Here is my code. I am using Javascript and jQuery to try and animate a module. Can someone please try and debug? Thanks.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
    var width = $(targetElement).width();
    $(targetElement).animate({
      marginLeft: "-=" + width
    }, {
      duration: speed,
      complete: function() {
        targetElement.animate({
          marginLeft: "+=" + width
        }, {
          duration: speed,
          complete: function() {
            animatethis(targetElement, speed);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };
  window.onload = animatethis($('.jeff'), 25000); // source of error here
</script>
```

Comment: I placed your code in to a snippet where it works (or at least, doesn't throw the error you describe). The error normally means you haven't included jQuery in the page correctly, or the URL.path to it is wrong, or you've included it but are trying to reference it too early in your own JS. None of those seem to be the case in your example. Are you sure the code you've shown is a representative example of your issue? Also note that jQuery 1.6.2 is *ancient*. You should really upgrade to 3.4.1

Comment: also try a more reliable cdn, or host it locally

Comment: Except for outdated jQuery, the code is working fine. Can you check to see if you can open http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js directly in the browser? Also maybe you can try loading the script over https.

Comment: Does your codebase have `noConflict` enabled anywhere? It's an option that makes `$` not used for jquery https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/